# Laravel registration failing with no error

Tags: php, laravel, forms, registration

I'm trying to a register 2 types of users( customers and venues ) and currently when I hit register (for registering venues) it just reloads the same page with no error messages. I can't figure out whats wrong with it. I've tried renaming the routes to no avail, and added a section to display any errors encountered which didn't work either.
Here's my code:

**register.blade:**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card" style="margin-top: 200px;">
                <div class="card-header">{{ ucfirst($url) }}{{ __(' Registration') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                   @isset($url)
                      <form method="POST" action='{{ route("venue.submit") }}' aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}">
                       <!--  <p style="position: relative; bottom: 50px;">{{ $url }}</p> -->
                    @else
                     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}">
                    @endisset
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control @error('fname') is-invalid @enderror" name="fname" value="{{ old('fname') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('fname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="lname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="lname" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="lname" value="{{ old('lname') }}" required autocomplete="lname" autofocus>

                                @error('lname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/login/customer', 'Auth\LoginController@showCustomerLoginForm');
Route::get('/login/venue', 'Auth\LoginController@showVenueLoginForm');
Route::get('/register/customer', 'Auth\RegisterController@showCustomerRegisterForm');
Route::get('/register/venue', 'Auth\RegisterController@showVenueRegisterForm');

Route::post('/login/customer', 'Auth\LoginController@customerLogin');
Route::post('/login/venue', 'Auth\LoginController@venueLogin');
Route::post('/register/customer', 'Auth\RegisterController@createCustomer');
Route::post('/register/venue', 'Auth\RegisterController@createVenue')->name('venue.submit');

Route::view('/home', 'home')->middleware('auth');
Route::view('/customer', 'customer');
Route::view('/venue', 'venue');
```

**Registration Controller:**

```
protected function createVenue(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $writer = venue::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'fname' => $request['fname'],
            'lname' => $request['lname'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
        return redirect('venue/2')->with('message', 'SIGNED UP VENUE');
    }
```

Any help wold be so fantastic! as I'm really new to Laravel :)

Comment: what jumps out at me is `{{ route('register') }}`, I don't see any route named register...

Comment: It wont get called on a register/venue or register/customer, But I tried changing it route('venue.submit') anyway just then, and it fails sadly :( @omn

Comment: If you open the page in DevTools, what do you see as the action of your form? I don't see anyway that you should see the same page again if your form is actually submitting to the controller you posted.

Comment: Oh, interesting, the action is register/venue... How could I make it use the createVenue method? As it should be using it

Comment: The next thing I would check is what output you are getting from {{ route('venue.submit') }}, just stick it in an html comment and see what value that is giving you

Comment: Yeah I get http://mylocalhostIPaddresse/register/venue

Comment: Are you sure there are no (invisible) validation errors? If not, please show us the validation rules.